# How does healthcare tie to residency and work in rural China?

Tags: china, healthcare

I know China has "universal healthcare", but I do not understand how Chinese healthcare works. I am told that healthcare in China is regional, and based on residency with the only way out of the residency requirement being the private market and healthcare. Specifically, I'm told that if someone in rural China gets bit by a deadly snake, if there is no hospital that can care for them regionally, they're not allowed to get on a high speed train and seek care at a better equipped hospital elsewhere. Does Chinese healthcare entitle citizens to access to hospitals anywhere? Or just at their local hospital?

Comment: Hmm, it used to be that China had - maybe they still do - internal barriers to rural people moving to the big cities.  The healthcare aspect might very well be an intentional feature to ensure control over residency.

Comment: There is not that much trouble NOW, but you still and just need to file with the government.